# twenty twenty one / background values

Tags: theme-twenty-twenty-one

have checked my source code of my wordpress site/theme using https://validator.w3.org/ because I have installed the new theme twenty twenty one and now the sites stalls on my iphone with an animation I used before. tools says:

> background: repeating-conic-gradient(from 0deg,rgb(236, 236, 236,
> 0.9) 0deg 1deg,transparent 1deg 2deg)

is an ERROR and  is not a background-color value? I can find quiet many examples in the web that say it should be that way? any advice?

regards, A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS conical gradient is still in the experimental stage and hasn’t been adopted yet by the majority of modern browsers. Only Google Chrome 69+ and Safari 12.1+ in desktop browsers and iOS Safari 12.2, Android 12.2+ and Chrome Android 67 among mobile browsers provide browser support for this feature. Other popular browsers like Mozilla Firefox, Opera and Edge still haven’t rolled out support for conical CSS gradient.

In order to provide CSS conical gradient functionality for unsupported browsers, you can make use of an ingenious polyfill by [Lea Verou](https://projects.verou.me/conic-gradient/).

Comment: That might be true, but I doubt that would help pass the W3.org validator or explain the site stalling on an iPhone.

Comment: Yes, it won't pass W3.org validator but it might help with cross-browser compatibility as she might be using an old version of Safari.